# Reset windows 7 local admin password on encrypted drive

Tags: windows-7, password, bitlocker, reset

I have lost administrator password on a windows 7 laptop running bitlocker.
I know bitlocker recovery password for this PC and can access BIOS setup.

I need to reset administrator password without removing HDD from the laptop.

1. Is there a way to do so without having to decrypt the drive first ?
2. If not, how can I decrypt the drive given the fact that I cannot login as admin to the machine ?

I am considering to boot Linux on a USB drive and run a copy of Windows 7 from Linux via Virtual box. Then try to decrypt laptop HDD from this copy of Windows 7.

I hope there is an easier way... If not, please tell me if you think this idea will fail or not.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a WinPE USB stick to boot but it must include the winpe-vmi package:

To create an image that can decrypt your first computer you'll need another computer with WAIK installed.

1.1 How to create a WinPE image that suits your needs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744533(v=ws.10).aspx

1.2 You should include the winpe-wmi package when adding packages.

```
Dism /image:C:\winpe_x86\mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files\<version>\Tools\PETools\<architecture>\WinPE_FPs\winpe-wmi.cab"

Dism /image:C:\winpe_x86\mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files\<version>\Tools\PETools\<architecture>\WinPE_FPs\en-us\winpe-wmi_en-us.cab"
```

You'll need both: the language neutral and the language specific (en-us) package. version can be Windows OPK or Windows AIK (WAIK).

1.3 Boot your first computer (the one where the password is lost) with WinPE and execute the following command:

```
cscript %systemroot%\system32\manage-bde.wsf –unlock Volume : -rk PathToExternalKeyFile: \ External Key File Name
```

If the Recovery Key is damaged or missing, you can still unlock the volume. To do this, type the following command at the command prompt:

```
cscript %systemroot%\system32\manage-bde.wsf –unlock Volume : -rp Numeric Recovery Password
```

source:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprosecurity/thread/984ca855-43ae-487c-ae6e-edd955b5d956/